# Matrix in reduced echelon form.

Tags: matrices

I'm stuck on this one assignment where I can't seem to solve the problem. I'm supposed to solve the matrix first matrix that you can see in the picture (1,2,3,4 etc). But I'm stuck on the step after multiplying the second row with 1/3. I get 0 1 2 3 4, as I should, but on the next step I want to multiply the third row with 1/5, but the solution shows that the third row should be 0 0 0 0. How is that possible? Thanks in advance.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HE041.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you multiply the second row by $-1/3$, you obtain row $[0\,1\,2\,3]$. After  you multiply the third row by $-1/5$, you obtain again row $[0\,1\,2\,3]$. Now subtract the second row from the third.

Comment: So you can just subtract entire rows from each other? I had no idea. I just started linear algebra today.

Comment: Yes, or  add a linear combination of rows to another row, or swap rows.

Comment: Thank you Bernard.

Comment: You're welcome! It's a pleasure to help.